# Sort by reverse option

Tags: finder, mojave, sort

When I arrange my folders with the `Sort by` option (I mostly use `Date added`) it will sort the files by the most recent one being the first and the oldest being the last.

I want to reverse this that the most recent added will be the last going back to the oldest being the first.

I would like to have this in the icon view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oddly enough macOS Finder does not (seem to) offer a reverse sort in anything but list view.

You can change the sort order in list view by clicking on the column heading and noting the direction the arrow points, either up or down.

But a sort order does not seem to be available in anything but list view.

Perhaps a Finder alternative/replacement (like Path Finder) will have the functionality you are looking for.

Also you can choose the columns if you right-click on a column heading. You **can** add the `Date Added` column. As shown below (Catalina 10.15.7)

[image: Finder Columns]

Comment: Yeah, also as far as it seems list view doesn't give you `Date added` as sortable option.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found XnView MP: https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/

It has a variety of sorting options, including sorting by some of EXIF data.